# Accessing nested template parameters without template template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, nested

I have this situation:

```
template<unsigned int N>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(){}
    int myint[N];
};

template<unsigned int M>
class BaseWrapper : Base<M>
{
public:
    BaseWrapper(){}
};

template<typename T>
class User
{
public:
    User(){}
    //int myint[T::N]; //How to statically allocate using M or N from above?
};

int main(void)
{
    User<BaseWrapper<10> > myuser;
    // Do something with User::myint here.
}
```

I want to be able to use the non-type parameter of the template argument to `User` to statically allocate data in the `User` class.  I know I can use template template parameters to create `BaseWrapper<M>` inside `User` but this is not my preferred approach.  Any simple methods to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add `static const unsigned int Size = N;` to your class.

Example:

```
template<unsigned int N>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(){}
    int myint[N];
    static const unsigned int Size = N;
};
```

Then `N` is accessible as `T::Size` in your `User` class.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

Declare a const static member data as:

```
template<unsigned int M>
class BaseWrapper : Base<M>
{
public:
    static const unsigned int size = M; //add this line!
    BaseWrapper(){}
};
```

Then use this as `T::size` in `User` class:

```
template<typename T>
class User
{
public:
    User(){}
    int myint[T::size];  //you can do this!
};
```

---

**Solution 2**

Or if you cannot add `size` as member (for whatever reason), then you can use this approach as:

```
template<typename T> struct get;

template<unsigned int N> 
struct get< BaseWrapper<N> > //partial specialization!
{
     static const unsigned int size = N;
};


template<typename T>
class User
{
public:
    User(){}
    int myint[get<T>::size];  //get the size!
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the template parameter as a static member variable of the class:

```
template<unsigned int M>
class BaseWrapper : Base<M>
{
public:
    static const int counter = M;
    BaseWrapper(){}
};
```

Then you can use this static member in your `User` class:

```
template<typename T>
class User
{
public:
    User(){}
    int myint[T::counter];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, which already has been mentioned by the others, is to add a static member to `Basewrapper` which is initialized to `N`.

However if for some reason you cannot change `User`, there's also a way to get at N:

```
template<typename T> struct get_N;
template<unsigned int N> struct get_N<Basewrapper<N> > { unsigned int const value = N; };
```

Now in your `User` template you just can write `get_N<T>::value`.

One advantage of this is that you can adapt any type after the fact without touching its definition, so if you ever want to instantiate `User` on anything else than a `Basewrapper`, say on `Newbasewrapper`, you just add the line

```
template<unsigned int N> struct get_N<Newbasewrapper<N> > { unsigned int const value = N; };
```

or if Newbasewrapper takes some type as template argument and provides the value of N as static const member,

```
template<typename T> struct get_N<Basewrapper<T> > { unsigned int const value = Basewrapper<T>::N; };
```